# What does "HEAD -> branch, origin/branch" mean in a git commit log?

Tags: git, command-line

I'm trying to understand the output of the git log command. Typically I see the HEAD pointing to a specific branch, but I'm confused about what is meant when HEAD appears to point to the local branch and the remote branch (HEAD -> branch, origin/branch).

I tried searching for the answer on the web but I wasn't even sure how how to write the question and the results that did show up didn't relate.

```
git log
commit 3b64cc50d6fe262d007853774689e8ad58e0f2ae (HEAD -> internal-env-board-david-fix, origin/internal-env-board-david-fix)
Author: user <user_email>
Date:   Some_Date

    Added build flag to platform.ini file: -D UAVCAN_CPP_VERSION=UAVCAN_CPP11
```

When I run `git log` as seen above, I don't know what `(HEAD -> internal-env-board-david-fix, origin/internal-env-board-david-fix)` means. Usually head only points to a single branch whereas here it seems to point to the local branch and the remote branch for some reason. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) says:

> How does Git know what branch you’re currently on? It keeps a special pointer called HEAD.... In Git, this is a pointer to the local branch you’re currently on. In this case, you’re still on master.

HEAD is pointing to a specific branch but the `git log` command is also showing you where the remote branch is in relation to your local branch. In this case the two branches line up at the same commit. That won't always be the case. All of this is described well with diagrams in [chapter 3](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Answer (score 1):

`(HEAD -> internal-env-board-david-fix, origin/internal-env-board-david-fix)` is the output mainly controlled by `--decorate[=short|full|auto|no]`. The output means "the ref names of any commits that are shown". If none is given, `--decorate=short` is used by default. To hide the output, use `--no-decorate`. To filter the output, use `--decorate-refs=<pattern>` and `--decorate-refs-exclude=<pattern>`. To find out all these refs, we can use `git for-each-ref --points-at=<commit>`.

In your case, `origin/internal-env-board-david-fix` is not directly related with `HEAD`. Both `internal-env-board-david-fix` and `origin/internal-env-board-david-fix` directly point at `3b64cc50d6fe262d007853774689e8ad58e0f2ae`, and `HEAD` points at only `internal-env-board-david-fix`. In other words, `HEAD` indirectly points at `3b64cc50d6fe262d007853774689e8ad58e0f2ae`. The sign `->` indicates the indirection. With `cat .git/HEAD`, it prints `ref: refs/heads/internal-env-board-david-fix`.

```
HEAD--->internal-env-board-david-fix--->3b64cc50d6fe262d007853774689e8ad58e0f2ae
origin/internal-env-board-david-fix------^
```

If we run `git checkout 3b64cc50d6fe262d007853774689e8ad58e0f2ae` to go to detached HEAD state, the decoration would be `(HEAD, internal-env-board-david-fix, origin/internal-env-board-david-fix)`, with the sign `->` gone. The content of `.git/HEAD` would become `3b64cc50d6fe262d007853774689e8ad58e0f2ae`. Now `HEAD` and the other two branches all directly point at `3b64cc50d6fe262d007853774689e8ad58e0f2ae`.

```
                        HEAD--->3b64cc50d6fe262d007853774689e8ad58e0f2ae
internal-env-board-david-fix-----^    ^
origin/internal-env-board-david-fix---|
```

Answer (score 0):

From [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56105758/6309):

> The sign `->` indicates the indirection. With `cat .git/HEAD`, it prints `ref: refs/heads/internal-env-board-david-fix`.

True. Except that reading HEAD directly from `.git/HEAD` will not always work in the future.

With Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), assorted changes around pseudoref handling.

See [commit 0a06892](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a06892ddde5bc3a82a4fe2963e3ea294252ffdd), [commit 70c70de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70c70de616c306cd4bb7c70426e394d08f929dff), [commit 668cdc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/668cdc043fe6f6d1fa2bf2b3f3c2375a20819e77), [commit 8f61321](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f61321ccbdea20945a73446f24a6c380cb2c53b) (14 Dec 2023) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dbf668a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dbf668a1b7d814b4fcb57c292934cbbc2d926490), 02 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`wt-status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f61321ccbdea20945a73446f24a6c380cb2c53b): read `HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` via the `refdb`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> We read both the HEAD and `ORIG_HEAD` references directly from the filesystem in order to figure out whether we're currently splitting a commit.
> If both of the following are true:
>
> - HEAD points to the same object as "rebase-merge/amend".
> - `ORIG_HEAD` points to the same object as "rebase-merge/orig-head".
>
> Then we are currently splitting commits.
>
> The current code only works by chance because we only have a single reference backend implementation.
> Refactor it to instead read both refs via the `refdb` layer so that we'll also be compatible with **alternate reference backends**.
>
> There are some subtleties involved here:
>
> - We pass `RESOLVE_REF_READING` so that a missing ref will cause `read_ref_full()` to return an error.
> - We pass `RESOLVE_REF_NO_RECURSE` so that we do not try to resolve symrefs.
>   The old code did not resolve symrefs either, and we only ever write object IDs into the refs in "`rebase-merge/`".
> - In the same spirit we verify that successfully-read refs are not symbolic refs.